# IIS error "Unable to cast object of type 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal'"

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

**Sample Code:**

```
staffName.Text = UserPrincipal.Current.Name;
```

Hi I have this error when I publish my project to IIS from vs2010. Can anyone help me, even then I tried delete away the code and references, I still get this error(which is strange).

**Error:**

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal' to type 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal'.
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
[InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal' to type 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal'.]
   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext context, IdentityType identityType, String identityValue) +57
   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.get_Current() +218
   Appraisal.Staffmain.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +121
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +91
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +74
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2207
```

Answer (score 1):

I would switch this to use the HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name attribute.

```
staffName.Text = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

This will give you the current user for the web application.

Comment: nice! it manage to run through but it displays nothing. (as in "")

Comment: You have to set the Current User via an authentication method.  If you are logging in anonymously I believe it will be blank.

Comment: I get a blank with the above.